# "Playlist vs segment duration mismatch" with HLS Streaming ts file

Tags: ios, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, wowza

I made a service which record a movie on iOS and publish it to the server. The server divides the stream to the multiple ts files. And by using these files, I make a m3u8 file and publish this file to the client.

However, mediastreamvalidator says that some ts files are invalid though I can play these ts files on Quick Time after I download these files.

Following is the output of the mediastreamvalidator

```html
Error: Playlist vs segment duration mismatch
--> Detail:  Segment duration 0.0000, Playlist duration: 12.0900
--> Source:  https://***.com/media/*** - https://storage.googleapis.com/***27.ts

--> Detail:  Segment duration 0.0000, Playlist duration: 12.0900
--> Source:  https://***.com/media/*** - https://storage.googleapis.com/***29.ts
```

I googled the error that "Error: Playlist vs segment duration mismatch" but there seems to be no answers.

Could you tell me the way to solve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the duration of segment 27 and 29.

Comment: ffprobe (and quick time) says the length of the ts file is equivalent to that number. However, mediastreamvalidator says the segment duration of the ts file is 0.0000.

Answer (score 0):

Your segments may have discontinuities between them.  If so you will need to enter the tag `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` between them.  The HLS spec specifies that you need to mark discontinuities in the following scenarios:

- file format
- number, type, and identifiers of tracks
- timestamp sequence

See Section 4.3.2.3: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216